# `carthage bootstrap` command results in `API rate limit exceeded` error in Github Actions workflow

Tags: ios, github-actions, carthage

I just moved my Xcode project to use Carthage instead of CocoaPods as my dependency manager, so I am trying to update my GitHub Actions CI workflow to download the dependency binaries.

However, after running `carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --use-xcframeworks` in my workflow, it eventually gives the output and error:

```
*** Cloning realm-cocoa
*** Skipped downloading realm-cocoa binary due to the error:
    "API rate limit exceeded for 199.19.85.26. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)"
```

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out! It turns out you need to specify the `GITHUB_TOKEN` as an environment variable when running the `carthage bootstrap` command. Here's the updated step in my workflow:

```
- name: Download Carthage dependencies
  env:
    GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  run: carthage bootstrap --platform iOS --use-xcframeworks
```

For reference, this Carthage [issue](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3058) and [pull request](https://github.com/cossacklabs/themis/pull/817) helped lead me to the answer.

#### Update Feb 1, 2023:

Even with the above solution, I still often get the `API rate limit exceeded` error. It's just random whether it occurs or not. Still haven't figured out a bulletproof solution.

Comment: Thanks for this. More information about what is the `GITHUB_TOKEN` can be found here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication

Comment: @wristbands Did you figure out why you randomly get this error even after setting up the `GITHUB_TOKEN`?